# Accurate pagination by datetime field

Tags: mysql, database, architecture, web, pagination

I have a database table, for example 'items'. I have a timeline of these items, sorted by field ascended_at (datetime). I need to make a pagination api for such timeline. So, the first my version was:

```
HTTP GET /items/timeline?page=[PAGE_NUM]
```

which fires

```
SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 10 OFFSET [0, 10, 20, ...] ORDER BY ascended_at;
```

but here is the problem: when new item arrives, all pages shifts per 1 item. To avoid this, i have added from_asc_at parameter:

```
HTTP GET /items/timeline?page=[PAGE_NUM]&from_asc_at=123123123
```

which fires

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE ascended_at <= [asc_at_parameter] LIMIT 10 OFFSET [0, 10, 20, ...] ORDER BY ascended_at;
```

but this is not accurate, because it is possible to have two items with same ascended_at, and you can see the same item in two different pages (but should not).

So, my question is: what are the possible solutions for this?

- Use ID (because it is unique)? But what if it is not ordered by ID?
- Any ideas more?

Answer (score 0):

If your items IDs are auto-incremented, you could check what will be the next "autoincrement" value when retrieving items the first time (before pagination).

Store that value persistently (maybe in a session var) until the next search, and add a filter `< {maximumID}` to your SQL query, to improve the "result set stability" when the user paginates (all new items created between the initial search and paginations won't be retrieved).

EDIT

To handle **items deletions**, you will have to do "soft deletes" : do not immediately delete an item from DB, but store a deletion date in a datetime field, so that items still exist in DB for a while.

When a new search is issued, you will store in session the current server time, and add a criteria (for example `date_deleted IS NULL OR date_deleted > {searchDate}`), so that all the items deleted after a search will still be displayed for that specific search.

You will have to create a scheduled job to "really" delete items from DB after some delay.

Comment: It seems to me, that it does not handle deletion of items